# In their old age, who should take care of Hindu parents who don't have any sons?

Tags: marriage, women, scripture, smriti, parents

We see many Hindu couples who don't have a single male child also.

Now assume one such couple have a single girl child and they find a suitable groom for her, get her married and send her off to the in-laws place.

According to smṛtis and dharma śāstras, who's responsible for taking care of the girl's parents in their old age? Is it their daughter, son-in-law, the society or all of them?

<sub>PS. Related questions but not duplicate:</sub>
<sub>1. [Are Hindu children meant to serve their parents forever whether they like them or not?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16256)</sub>
<sub>2. [Poem on taking care of parents at their old age](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2912/2995)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Here is an answer which is only indicative but not the most definite one

According to me,the parents who don't have a son, but have a daughter, have the following two options:

**1)Adopt a son.**

> Manu Smriti 9.141. Of the man who has an adopted (Datrima) son
>   possessing all good qualities, that same (son) shall take the
>   inheritance, though brought from another family.

Since,the adopted son is inheriting its his duty to look after the parents.

**2)Make the daughter an "appointed daughter":**

> Manu Smriti 9.127. He who has no son may **make his daughter in the
>   following manner an appointed daughter (putrika, saying to her
>   husband), ’The (male) child, born of her, shall perform my funeral
>   rites.**

Now,an appointed daughter's son is as good as a son's son.

> Manu 9.133. **Between a son’s son and the son of an (appointed) daughter
>   there is no difference, neither with respect to worldly matters nor to
>   sacred duties;** for their father and mother both sprang from the body
>   of the same (man)

So,i guess its the duty of the the appointed daughter to look after her parents like a son and thereafter the responsibility shifts on her son.

Now,in case, she(the appointed daughter) dies without a male issue ,then the duty shifts on her husband.The following verse indicate only that:

> Manu 9.135. But if an appointed daughter by accident dies without
>   (leaving) a son, the husband of the appointed daughter may, without
>   hesitation, take that estate.

And,in the case,when the old parents don't have anyone , neither a daughter nor an adopted son ,then the duty(of looking after them) rests on their relatives etc.

> The father, the mother, the preceptor, the wife, the children, the
>   poor people, the dependants, the incomers and the guests, are spoken
>   of as the Poshyas (i.e., those who should be supported .
>
> > (29)**Kinsmen,relatives, those suffering from diseases, who have none to look after them, those who seek refuge, and others having no means, are also
> >     spoken of  as the Poshyas**
>
> (30) To support the Poshyas, is the most
>    excellent expedient for attaining to the celestial region(Daksha Smriti)

.

Comment: "appointed daughter...saying to her husband"...means take permission from the son-in-law?

Comment: I think its just a declaration & not exactly taking permission from the SIL..